# For lognormal distribution which one is preferred? Log 10 or Ln or Log 2?

Tags: lognormal-distribution, logarithm

I want to perform a linear regression analysis. The distributions of data for all continuous variables are not normal. The tail of graph is to the right and thre highest point of graph is due to the left. (I know that in this situation we can change data by using log. (if the highest point is in the right and the tail of graph in the left ^2 could be used.) Now I think Log 10 is a better option. What about Ln or log 2? Is there a rule about the type of Log in this situation?

Comment: Do you prefer inches or centimeters?  Pounds or kilograms?  That's the *only* difference among any two bases of logarithm: a constant multiplicative factor.

Comment: 1. None of the variables are assumed to be normal for linear regression analysis. If you're doing testing or confidence intervals or prediction intervals based off the most commonly used approaches, the error term is assumed to be normal in those (corresponding to the conditional distribution of the response). You can't assess that by looking at the marginal distribution of the response variable (nor any of the predictors). 2. It makes no difference to anything which base of logs you use when you do take logs (as long as you're consistent with your choice).

Comment: @ Glen_b Thank you, So the distribution of dependent variable is not important, and the distribution of the residuals (for dependent variable) should be normal?  Meanwhile they are not normal too. I think I should check linearity and variances before using Log.

Comment: https://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-linear-regression/

Comment: In above link says about assumptions of linear regression

Comment: "Secondly, the linear regression analysis requires all variables to be multivariate normal.  This assumption can best be checked with a histogram or a Q-Q-Plot."

Comment: This is confusing for me!

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, you can't believe everything you read on random sites on the internet. The person who wrote that is simply wrong; it's easy to see what the assumptions are if you know what things you use in deriving the results for tests and intervals (which they clearly have never done). I suggest you avoid visiting it again -- if they're *that* clueless about what the assumptions are in regression, who knows what else they might say.  ... ctd

Comment: ctd... 2. The errors are assumed normal (but this assumption is almost never going to be true; on the other hand, most properties are not super sensitive to mild violations of this assumption); if you wish to check this assumption, residuals (which are your estimate of the errors) should be approximately normal; a QQ plot should suffice. Yes, getting linearity and the variance assumptions approximately correct is a more important issue than the error distribution. If you have linearity and constant variance but non-normal errors you may want to ask a new question.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you so much, I think there is a controversy about doing multivariate normality testing in multiple linear regression, meanwhile it seems recent papers consider this as unnecessary to some extent.

Comment: No, I am sorry, I must protest. This has been well understood since the normal-based hypothesis tests (F- and t-tests), CI's & PIs for regression were first derived. There has been no controversy on it at any time in about 90(?) years nor any recent change that could excuse the magnitude of that error. There have, however, been a large number of people who get it wrong, simply because they've never even looked at the actual mathematics involved but relied on statements from other people who also have never looked at it. They share their ignorance widely and it gets passed down generations.

Comment: People may have arguments about it in some application areas. Imagine a collection of skilled plumbers arguing about physics (say, about the physics of turbulence, which will have some relevance for their job). Some will have actual knowledge of the physics and know what they're talking about but many will be speaking from a position of ignorance, having never opened an actual physics book written by a phsyicist, but only having heard about it from things said or written by other plumbers. Such disagreements may go on for long periods among them without constituting a controversy in physics.

Comment: There's really no basis for substantive argument on it. There's simply no assumption of multivariate normality of all variables for inference in ordinary multiple linear regression with continuous predictors. The mathematics is clear; we condition on the x's and we assume conditional normality for the y (normality of the error). That's what's assumed about the distribution in order to derive the t-tests, F-tests and the corresponding intervals etc. Simply doing the mathematics -- which is within the grasp of generations of undergraduate statisticians, it's not hard -- is sufficient to see this

Comment: @whuber I certainly prefer centimeters to inches

Comment: @Slow Jason W. Osborne's PhD is in ... educational psychology. I will happily defer to him on that topic. His main reference for the claim of multivariate normality as an assumption appears to be Tabachnik & Fidell, which is brim full of errors of exactly this kind. Note that both of them are psychologists as well. So this is precisely the problem I was referring to. A person whose actual training in psychology, using other psychologists to support their claims in a publication outside of statistics does not in any sense constitute a controversy in statistics.

Comment: Not having statistical training doesn't mean of itself that the claims are wrong, but check their sources and their sources' sources. Do any of them offer a lick of proof for Osborne's statement? Now I keep talking about the mathematics. Guess what? I can prove it, if you're prepared to sit and read a few pages of mathematics - though most of it can be found in standard references and here on our site.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, fortunately the time solves most of the scientific problems and errors

Comment: These errors have persisted for generation upon generation. Osborne's references are nearly all written by psychologists some of whom have been writing on this topic since at least the 60s, and are being read and believed by other psychologists / social scientists. If psychology acts as a closed shop for its statistical knowledge while never demanding proof, how will the errors get corrected? Certainly there are knowledgeable people in psychology who do know better, but it looks they're not going to be carrying the day any time soon.

Comment: For a contradiction of the Osborne article you linked, see https://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=18&n=11 -- unfortunately it's been viewed considerably less often than the one you looked at

Comment: Glen_b Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are solving a plain OLS analytically (i.e. using psuedoinverse, as in most statistical packages), then the base of the log doesn't matter since it will just be a constant multiplicative factor like @whuber mentioned.

But if you have a large dataset and solving the regression via some iterative algorithm such as stochastic gradient descent, then choosing a proper log base could help with convergence speed.

- Pick a log base such that the variance of the transformed attribute is comparable to that of other attributes
- Picking the wrong log base will still converge to the same answer eventually, it just affects convergence speed

Comment: I have a hard time believing this: could you demonstrate how simply rescaling the response values by the relatively smalll amounts involved in converting between bases $2,$ $e,$ and $10$ could have any effect on convergence rates?  Note, too, that most (good) software performs an internal initial standardization of the data, which means that by the time it begins iterating, the units of measurement don't matter at all.

Comment: I don't think the typical internal standardization handles lognormal transformation, but do let me know if there's software/packages that does that and I'd love to know more

Comment: In terms of scaling/normalizing with a different base, it depends on the algorithm but the general idea is that a feature with much higher variance than the others could dominate the next descent step, thus slowing down convergence. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling